# SlideToggle :visible - problem with multiple toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden, visible

I am trying to apply a class to my button so that when the toggled div is shown, the button is yellow. I have it working fine, but when I click to the 2nd button (rather than toggling the same button again) it causes issues.

I've copied in my JQuery code below, my html and css is just the buttons and drop down elements. I'm new to Javascript so I'm sure it's something relatively simple I'm missing. Any help?

Here's a gif of the problem - https://gph.is/g/EGneVln

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
      $(".icon1").click(function(){         // Slide down contact form //
      $("#cf-block").slideToggle(500,"linear");
      $("#nwl-block").not("#cf-block").hide();
      $(".icon1").removeClass('active');      // Highlight contact icon //
      if ($("#cf-block").is (':visible')) {
      $('.icon1').addClass('active');
      }
      });
  
      $(".icon2").click(function(){         // Slide down contact form //
      $("#nwl-block").slideToggle(500,"linear");
      $("#cf-block").not("#nwl-block").hide();
      $(".icon2").removeClass('active');      // Highlight contact icon //
      if ($("#nwl-block").is (':visible')) {
      $('.icon2').addClass('active');
      }
      });
  
});
```

```
<div id="connectblock" class="ct-div-block">
  <h1 id="headline-523-16" class="ct-headline lrg-font">Get connected</h1>
    <div id="connecticons" class="ct-div-block">
      <div id="contacticon" class="ct-div-block">
        <svg class="icon1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        viewBox="XXXX"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div id="newslettericon" class="ct-div-block">
        <svg class="icon2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        viewBox="XXXX"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div id="instagramicon" class="ct-div-block">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hausseuk/" target="_blank">
          <svg class="icon2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
          viewBox="XXXX"/></svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.icon1{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  stroke:#000;
}
.icon2{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  stroke:#000;
}
.active{
  stroke:#FFD66E;
}
```

Comment: 1) change the `activeN` class to a single common `active` class which works on all icons. 2) Put a common class on all the icons themselves and call `removeClass('active')` on that before adding it to the clicked one. 3) DRY up your code. There's no need to repeat the same block for every icon/slide panel. If you want an example of this, please add all the relevant HTML and CSS to the question.

Comment: I've followed this but I think I'm making a mistake with adding the 'active' class back on on click. I'm adding in all my code including what I've updated now.. cheers!

Comment: Hi, can you show proper html code ?

Comment: Just updated with it ^

Comment: Updated again, should be a little cleaner.

Comment: Well, your svg's are broken, for one thing. They don't have any content and the svg-tag itself is closed /> while there is a </svg> as well. Then: one div has a <a>, the others don't. So not clear what you want exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I just blanked them out with the XXXX to save a bit of space. They're linked in properly and display fine on my actual build, so that's not an issue. Only the last icon needs to link anywhere so that's why it's wrapped with the <a>. I don't think that's related to my problem exactly as it's the jQuery 'active' class toggle which is the bit causing me problems.